# не правильно считает слова,если в конце строки поставить несколько пробелов

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
void ShiftLeft(char *s,int pos)
{
 int i;
  for(i=pos;s[i+1];i++)
   s[i]=s[i+1];
   s[i]='\0';
 }
int main()
{
char s[80];
 int k=0,i,pos;
 fgets (s,80,stdin);
 puts (s);
 for (i=0;s[i];i++)
  if (s[i]==' ' && s[i+1]==' ')
  {
   ShiftLeft(s,i);
   i--;
  }
 for (i=0;i<s[i];i++)
  if ((s[strlen(s)-1])==' ')
   s[strlen(s)-1]='\0';
 puts(s);
 int n=strlen(s);
 printf("%d\n", n);
 for(i=0; s[i]; i++) 
  if (s[i]==' ') 
   k++;
 printf ("%d",k+1);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Проверка цикла i < s[i]? Т.е. число меньше символа?

Comment: s[i] это последний символ=\0

Comment: Так зачем сравнивать i и s[i]?

Comment: На порядок проще было бы просто взять и сразу посчитать количество слов в строке, не занимаясь предварительным "причесыванием" строки, т.е. удалением лишних пробелов. И что в этом коде делает `#include <math.h>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
void ShiftLeft(char *s,int pos)
{
 int i;
 for(i=pos;s[i+1];i++)
  s[i]=s[i+1];
  s[i]='\0';
}
int main()
{

char s[80];
int k=0,i,pos;
fgets (s,80,stdin);
puts (s);
for (i=0;s[i+1];i++)
if (s[i]==' ' && s[i+1]==' ')
{
 ShiftLeft(s,i);
 i--;

}
puts(s);
for(i=0; s[i]; i++) 
 if (s[i]==' ' && s[i+1]!=' ' && s[i+2]!='\0') 
  k++;
printf ("%d",k+1);
return 0;
}
```